# Hessian binary web service protocol- C language

Tags: java, c, hessian

I want to use Hessian binary web protocol (http://hessian.caucho.com/) for a J2EE server and I need to communicate with the server using C code (low level hardware devices, that cannot handle C++ programs).

I understand that C is not the object oriented language, but **is there available any (limited) library, that is possible to call some simple methods**, e.g.:

```
 void hello(int number, String name);
```

Comment: You can rewrite C++ implementation to C, it is no very big.

Comment: Yes, there probably are string api's written in C, but if you're only after a couple of methods, then perhaps writing your own will do just fine: define the string type as a struct, containing a `char *self`, and a `size_t length` member, then add function pointers for the methods you need, and define a couple of macro's to make invoking these methods feel more natural